# Can't get Oracle instance to dynamically register with Listener after Cold Restore

Tags: oracle11g, listener

I am installing a new host to upgrade/transfer the Oracle instance to, on Windows 2012 R2.  When I create empty instances in the same path as Production, they start up, dynamically register, and I can connect just great.  So I shut down the instance, copy the ORADATA files over, and start it up just like I do all day long on other systems, but when I do LSNRCTL STAT, the instance no longer shows up as registered.  Of course, when I try to connect, I get ORA-12514 (because it didn't register).  What am I missing?  Thanks!

As further info, I am doing a cold transfer because it is part of a replicated environment, so I want to transfer everything.

Answer (score 0):

I had failed to restore the SPFILE in the \database folder.  Once I did that, the service registered with the listener fine.